# What is a robust browser-based method for uploading (very) large files?

Tags: file-upload

I'm looking at replacing our current file-upload solution, a bespoke java application which transmits files and metadata using sftp, with a browser-based solution. My intention is to have finer-grained control over who can and cannot upload by tying the upload to an authenticated session in a web app. This will also enable me to collect reliable data about who uploaded what when, etc, in a straight-forward manner.

My concern is that we need to be able to support uploading huge files- think 100GB or more. As such, I don't think standard HTTP is appropriate- I don't trust it to be reliable, and I want to be able to provide user feedback such as progress bars.

The best idea I've come up with so far is an embedded applet which uses sftp to push the file, but I'd like to do this using only js or similar if at all possible.

Comment: If it were me, I would put all the effort into customizing the _server_ end of things and leave the client 100% alone -- I can't imagine there being any benefit to reimplementing `ssh` and `sftp` in JavaScript (though I guess there's the fame of being The Guy...) -- you can do all the authentication control in the server without modifying your current client workflow. If none of the existing PAM modules suits your needs, you could write your own easily enough...

Comment: The reason I'm after tying the upload to a web session is that I want to track the file and associated information in a database- I also want to be able to include arbitrary metadata with uploads. If I can possibly get free of using sftp at all, I would love to, as having a single user account is insecure and provisioning new accounts for each user is cumbersome and not scalable.

Comment: [You can avoid the account provisioning if you're willing to work in Python](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/) -- though your application would then be 100% responsible for keeping client data separate from each other.

Comment: For example, I would love to use HTTP for the whole thing- just probably not one single HTTP file upload per file. Maybe use js to chunk it and transmit it, with some asynchronous magic to drive a progress bar. I'm just worried that javascript's memory management isn't robust enough to load and transmit 100GB worth of data without leaking all over the place. Am I right to be concerned about this?

Comment: Don't forget to also compute a checksum over the entire file; TCP's CRC-based checksum is good for roughly one mistake every four gigabytes. If you use TLS over HTTP, of course you'll get cryptographically strong assurances over the transfer, but you've got to be sure to either use TLS or re-implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is project that want to enable resumable uploads: https://tus.io/.

Its client library provides progress bar and resume-on-interruption in the browser.

You can integrate the server part into your app, to manage authentication yourself, while benefiting from the resumability!

Here is a blog post https://tus.io/blog/2018/09/25/adoption.html in which they mention it being used by Cloudflare.